# sphinxsearch , Mysql like : order by lang='2' desc , time_popular desc

Tags: search, sorting, sphinx

is it possible with sphinx to sort a result like this mysql query?
order by lang='2' desc , time_popular desc
so get the latest documents with lang=2 in fist position.
I really need your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Look at this page http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sorting-modes and particularly SPH_SORT_EXTENDED.

Assuming you have attributes for them both:

sql_attr_uint = lang
sql_attr_timestamp = time_popular

Then using the API for example:

$cl->SetSortMode ( SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, "lang desc, time_popular desc" );

Answer (score 0):

You could use filer along with order like

```
SELECT * FROM your_index where lang=2 order by lang desc, time_pupular desc;
```

Hope it helps.